# Что означают SB, FP, NOSPLIT?

Tags: golang, ассемблер

Всем привет!

Помогите пожалуйста, разобрать Go asm функцию

```
TEXT runtime·sysMmap(SB),NOSPLIT,$0
    MOVQ    addr+0(FP), DI
    MOVQ    n+8(FP), SI
    MOVL    prot+16(FP), DX
    MOVL    flags+20(FP), R10
    MOVL    fd+24(FP), R8
    MOVL    off+28(FP), R9

    MOVL    $SYS_mmap, AX
    SYSCALL
    CMPQ    AX, $0xfffffffffffff001
    JLS ok
    NOTQ    AX
    INCQ    AX
    MOVQ    $0, p+32(FP)
    MOVQ    AX, err+40(FP)
    RET
ok:
    MOVQ    AX, p+32(FP)
    MOVQ    $0, err+40(FP)
    RET
```

1. Что означают SB, FP, NOSPLIT?
2. Что означают addr, n, prot, flags, fd, off? Это символы? это адреса символов? Как они мапятся на стек? Можно ли записать это так:

Пример:

```
subq $40, %rsp
movq %rbp, 32(%rsp)
leaq 32(%rsp), %rbp

movq addr, (%rsp)
movq n, 8(%rsp)
movl prot, 16(%rsp)
movl flags, 20(%rsp)
movl fd, 24(%rsp)
movl off, 28(%rsp)
```

а потом прочесть как

```
movq (%rsp), %RDI
movq 8(%rsp),%RSI
movl 16(%rsp), %RDX
movl 20(%rsp), %R10
movl 24(%rsp), %R8
movl 28(%rsp), %R9
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответы на все эти вопросы есть в [документации](https://golang.org/doc/asm):

> - `FP`: Frame pointer: arguments and locals.
> - `PC`: Program counter: jumps and branches.
> - `SB`: Static base pointer: global symbols.
> - `SP`: Stack pointer: top of stack.

(…)

> `NOSPLIT = 4`
>
> (For `TEXT` items.) Don't insert the preamble to check if the stack must be split. The frame for the routine, plus anything it calls, must fit in the spare space at the top of the stack segment. Used to protect routines such as the stack splitting code itself.